# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths throwing __NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:'object cannot be nil' error

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I am trying to insert an item to my table view dynamically. My app has a chat section, where it displays the old (loaded from server before initializing the view controller) messages in section 0, and displays just sent/received messages (where it is initially zero) in section 1. When the view is loaded, all the "old" messages are loaded and displayed, no problem is there. The problem starts when I try to insert rows. Here is what I am doing:

- I am first updating my table view's data source by adding an extra item: `[newMessages addObject:newMessage];` (newMessage is an instance of my custom message object, and newMessages is my data source). I verify that my data source now has 1 item (which was 0 before adding).
- I then call the following code:

  ```
  [self.chatTableView beginUpdates];
  [self.chatTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath 
      indexPathForRow:newMessages.count - 1 inSection:1]] 
      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
  [self.chatTableView endUpdates];
  ```

My app crashes at `endUpdates` method, giving me this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

I've immediately checked if `newMessage` is `nil` or not, it's **not** `nil` (and re-checked my data source) so data source is not the problem. I've thought that `indexPathForRow:newMessages.count - 1` could be the problem and tried different values (count - 2, count, count + 1) just in case I was missing something. In those cases, I'm getting another error: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 1, but there are only 1 rows in section 1 after the update'`. The error says it all, so the problem is not something with `indexPathForRow:newMessages.count - 1` either.

I've added breakpoints into the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to see when it's exactly called and what it returns. It seems that the method is not called at all, the breakpoint is not hitting (it DOES hit when view is first loaded and loads the initial data correctly, and I'm not setting data source anywhere, so delegates/data sources are also connected correctly). Immediately I've checked other methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0){
        return @"Eski mesajlar";
    }else{
        return @"Yeni mesajlar";
    }
}
```

Those methods return correct values. I've put a breakpoint in `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` to see when it's called. It apparently *is* called inside the `[self.chatTableView endUpdates];` method (as seen from the thread/queue's call stack), but then `[self.chatTableView endUpdates];` immediately throws the error without even entering `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method. I've seen examples (and a few others) such as:

- [how to properly use insertRowsAtIndexPaths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943470/how-to-properly-use-insertrowsatindexpaths)
- [Error creating row in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848913/error-creating-row-in-tableview)
- [Add cell to bottom of UITableView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874917/add-cell-to-bottom-of-uitableview-in-ios)
- [Tableview crashes when moving more than half the cells to another section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035652/tableview-crashes-when-moving-more-than-half-the-cells-to-another-section)

I've read the answers there, but none of them helped me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do you have `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` implemented? I've noticed a similar issue inside one of my own applications that used an `NSFetchedResultsController` where the application would crash with the same error message when `tableView:endUpdates` was called. Commenting out `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` fixed it for me.

Comment: Exactly. I had that method, and commenting out it fixed the issue. Thanks, I probably would never have figured it out, I'll be filing a bug report to Apple.

Comment: I'm not using a fetched results controller, but basing mine off of networked data and I can confirm that commenting out the estimatedHeight section stopped my crash as well.

Comment: This answer saved my life! Resolved a crash AND made the insertion animations FAR smoother! Thanks!

Comment: When you remove the `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method (or stop using the `estimatedRowHeight` property), just make sure you fully understand what you're doing. You're now forcing the table view to call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for **every** row in the table view before anything can be shown *and* at every call to `reloadData` or similar -- major performance impact! As such, removing the usage of row height estimation is not really a fix, just a workaround for what appears to be an Apple bug. (@CanPoyrazoğlu do you have the radar # for the bug you filed?)

Comment: The bug ID is 16246389 but as it's fixed in iOS 7.1, bug is in closed state now.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Interesting! Alfie Hanssen was saying he ran into this, sounds like it was on an older version of iOS or a different issue altogether.

Comment: @smileyborg The bug is apparent in iOS 7.0. It has been corrected on 7.1, and I don't know about the versions prior to 7.0. He is probably on iOS 7.0.

Comment: I don't think this "bug" is completely resolved because I'm having the same crash/Exception issue and commenting out tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: makes it go away (but makes tableView scrolling jerky and unusable.)

Comment: Removing any `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` calls is not the way to go about this. This is a very important delegate method. I'd say to try out @speby's answer below before you go removing important delegate methods/properties.

Comment: Crash is still happening for dynamic header height. This saved my week :)

Answer (score 11):

Regarding removing/commenting out `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`, that was not how I resolved it since I did not have that method on my delegate.

Instead, I had actually set `tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 10.;` in my `viewDidLoad`. Turns out by simply commenting that line out, the exception no longer occurs and this then works as I expect it to.

It's too bad, though, because I can't say why commenting this out (or the `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method) fixes it.

Comment: This helped me, removing any `tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` and `tableView.sectionHeaderHeight` calls fixed this up for me. This isn't the first time they've caused me trouble...I'm just going to pretend they don't exist from now on, because they only break things...

Comment: This fixed the problem for me too, on iOS 9.2 (!)

Comment: Dear Lord, this is what helped me too! Thank you for existing @speby !
I _had_ to keep the `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`  tho, otherwise it would still fail.

Comment: You're welcome @Gee.E! Glad I could help. This was a real time sink for awhile!

Answer (score 3):

I recently resolved this issue without commenting out `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  The specific issue I had was that our table had many cells with different sizes and so we were simply using the average size in the estimation.  The fix was to better estimate the size of the inserted cells.

My assumption is that the bug is caused by the table attempting to scroll to the inserted cell.  Apparently the previously estimated contentSize causes issues when scrolling to inserted cells with heights that were estimated too small.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and fixed it by not inserting if the table is empty. In other words if the table has no rows then don't use `insertRowAtIndexPaths`. Instead add the object to your array or whatever data source and then call `[myTableView reloadData]`

Answer (score -2):

I believe your error is in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. The `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` method will call this method before calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it this doesn't match to the data source, it could be the problem.

I see that `newMessages` is a local variable, so that way it is probably not synchronised to the array that returns from `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

**To fix the problem, just make sure the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection returns the correct number when doing the updates.**

*In addition: even if newMessages was nil, the count method would return 0 - Objective-C works that way.*